# How to upgrade MySQL 5.6 to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, freebsd, upgrade, mariadb

We are using MySQL 5.6 on a productive Server which we want to migrate to MariaDB. Many reasons - but the main reason is the way the Master <-> Master Replication on MariaDB is working.

There are many Drop in REplacement Guides regarding Crossgrade from MySQL 5.5 to Mariadb (which also worked in our tests), BUT in our tests the mariadb drop in replacement did not work properly when executed on an MySQL 5.6 based Machine.

Is there any Hint on how this could work?

Bonus Point for Hints how this is done on Freebsd 10.0

Comment: To be safe, I would do a full dump and reload.

Comment: Also you haven't use the 10.0 because of bugs and vulnerabilities. 10.1 is way better.

Comment: Well - you're right - on the Server is indeed FreeBSD 10.1 installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop-in replacement for MySQL-5.6 is MariaDB-10.0.x, not the 5.5 release. And even then I'm not sure all features of Mysql already ported to the MariaDB.

At the time current version of `databases/mariadb100-server` is 10.0.17. You can replace ports this way:

```
pkg delete -f mysql56-server
pkg delete -f mysql56-client
make -C /usr/ports/databases/mariadb100-server install clean
```

I hope you'll try all that on the test machine first.

Comment: pkg search  
showed me that there are packages ready  
'mariadb100-client-10.0.17
mariadb100-server-10.0.17'  
why do you promote the self compiled version?

Comment: Oops. Mental inertion. I've used compiled software from ports only as far as precompiled packages in general do not have required options enabled. If packaged version compiled well - you can use it.

Comment: But why is in the mariadb docs the migration only mentioned up to mariadb 5.5 ?   Oh - and the first test looks good... ;-)

Comment: There is a lag between developement and documenting :) If you want be in touch - read the changelogs.

Comment: the update worked - but I used the "pkg install mariadb100-client mariadb100-server" command extended by "mysql_upgrade" that did the trick

Comment: `mysql_upgrade` always necessary even on minor version updates. And client is required by server and installed anyway.